# How can I refresh a child component from a parent component multiple times from the same method?

Tags: c#, .net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

Right now my child component only updates once the `GetLeads()` method in the parent component is finished. I never see the spinner or Searching text.

Parent Component:

```
<SearchResultComponent  @ref="ChildComponent"></SearchResultComponent>
```

Code:

```
 protected SearchResultComponent ChildComponent;
 public int LeadsFound { get; set; }
 public void GetLeads()
 {
      ChildComponent.Refresh(true, 0);
      var leads  = _searchService.Search(searchRequest);
      LeadsFound = leads?.Count ?? 0;
      _writeFileService.WriteToFile(leads);
      ChildComponent.Refresh(false, LeadsFound);
  }
```

Child Component:

```
@code {

    public bool Searching { get; set; } = false;
    public int LeadsFound { get; set; } = 0;
    public void Refresh(bool searching, int leadsFound)
    {
        Searching = searching;
        LeadsFound = leadsFound;
        StateHasChanged();
    }
}

@if (Searching)
{
    <div>Searching...</div>
    <div>
        <img src="~/Content/searching-spinner.gif" />
    </div>
}
else
{
    <div>Leads Found: @LeadsFound</div>
}
```

Comment: How do you trigger GetLeads() ?

Comment: Why isn't `_searchService.Search(searchRequest)` async?  Same for `WriteToFile()`

Comment: Button click. @onclick="@GetLeads"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> my child component only updates once

You can make the eventhandler async. That allows you then to call `Task.Delay(1)` or `Task.Yield()` and that will effectuate the StateHasChanged().

The call form `@onclick="@GetLeads"` can remain the same. Note that you don't need the 2nd `@` in there.

If your `searchService.Search()` was async then you wouldn't need `Task.Yield()`

```
 public async Task GetLeads()
 {
      ChildComponent.Refresh(true, 0);      
      await Task.Yield();  // enable the render thread to run.
      var leads  = _searchService.Search(searchRequest);
      LeadsFound = leads?.Count ?? 0;
      _writeFileService.WriteToFile(leads);
      ChildComponent.Refresh(false, LeadsFound);
  }
```